# Проблема с циклом, не удается нормально скомпилировать

Tags: java

Есть метод в программе, в него передается одномерный массив длиной в 20 элементов. Необходимо проверить, есть ли в очередном значении строчной переменной цифра. Вот что я набросал:

```
public static void valueDistribution(String[] valueArray) {
        for (i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
            char[] c = valueArray[i].toCharArray();
            if (Character.isDigit(c[i])) {
                System.out.println("Есть число");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Нет числа");
            }
        }
    }
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 8
Подскажите, в чем проблема, заранее спасибо

Comment: А по внимательнее посмотреть что вы делаете?? ВЫ получаете сначала массив символов, а томот пытаетесь конкретный символ посмотреть. А это не факт что он есть

Comment: Ну так я очередное значение массива строк преобразую в массив чаров. Потом эти чары проверяются на цифры, все работает адекватно до 8 итерации

Comment: _не удается нормально скомпилировать_ -- данный код **компилируется** без проблем, исключение `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` выбрасывается во **время исполнения (run time)** и указывает на выход за пределы массива, так как индекс `i` относится к _строке_ во входном массиве `valueArray`, а не к символу в массиве `c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать регулярное выражение для проверки строки:

```java
public static void valueDistribution(String ... valueArray) {
    for (String s : valueArray) {
        if (s.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
            System.out.println("Содержит хотя бы одну цифру");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не содержит цифр");
        }
    }
}
```

Решение с вложенными циклами

```java
public static void valueDistribution(String ... valueArray) {
    for (String s : valueArray) {
        boolean hasDigit = false;
        for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n && !hasDigit; i++) {
            hasDigit = Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i));
        }
        if (hasDigit) {
            System.out.println("Содержит хотя бы одну цифру");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не содержит цифр");
        }
    }
}
```

Решение с использованием Stream API:

```java
public static void valueDistribution(String ... valueArray) {
    for (String s : valueArray) {
        if (s.chars().anyMatch(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
            System.out.println("Содержит хотя бы одну цифру");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не содержит цифр");
        }
    }
}
```